# Selecting problems of the appropriate difficulty based for adaptive learning

Tags: machine-learning

I'm currently working on an adaptive learning system for high school maths. Students complete questions in quizzes and I need to be able to select questions of the appropriate difficulty level (say approximately 75% chance of being correct) and create a competency metric for measuring the skill of a student at a particular subtopic. We don't have explicit information about the difficulty of the questions or the abilities of the students - both need to be inferred from the data. The questions are broken down into topics and sub-topics (each question is assigned a single topic and sub-topic) and we have a dependency graph indicating which sub-topics depend on other sub-topics, so we can take into account the student's performance on areas outside of the subtopic.

How can I estimate the chance of a student getting a question correct based on historical data and create metrics for the difficulties of questions and skill levels of students?

Comment: I have a similar task. Did you ever find a good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You could Item Response Theory or it's more complex version Hierarchical Item Response Theory. It will estimate students abilities and items difficulty to produce probability of success using models based on logistic regressions.